# Perl Win32::OLE returns empty object from COM object

Tags: perl, excel, com, vba

I'm trying to port a routine using COM objects in Excel VBA to Perl using Win32::OLE.  The main reason is that it would improve the speed somewhat because VBA is slow with array iteration.

The following code works fine in VBA:

```
Function LoadServerSignal(name As String, timeRange As FooCOMLib.timeRange) As FooCOMLib.SerieValues
    Dim server as object
    Dim signal As FooCOMLib.signal
    Dim fooData As New FooCOMLib.SerieValues

    Set server = New FooCOMLib.Recorder
    fooData.initialize (0)

    If server.SignalContents.FindSignalByName(name, signal) Then
       Set fooData = server.LoadSignal(signal, timeRange)
    End If

    Set LoadServerSignal = fooData

End Function
```

The requested signal name is passed through the **name** string.  The server finds the name and returns the data in the **signal** object via the *FindSignalByName* object method.

I tried porting the same thing to Perl using the Win32::OLE library.  Most of the items which take or return a simple scalar object work fine.  But the same code to return the **$signal** object always returns empty.

```
#!perl -w
use strict;
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Variant;

my $server = Win32::OLE->new('FooCOMLib.Recorder');
my $signal = Win32::OLE->new('FooCOMLib.signal');
my $timeRange = Win32::OLE->new('FooCOMLib.timeRange');
my $fooData = Win32::OLE->new('FooCOMLib.SerieValues');    
my $name = "FooTran76";

$fooData->initialize(0);
$timerange->{StartTime} = 40909;   # Jan 1, 2012
$timerange->{EndTime} = 40910;     # Jan 2, 2012

$server->{SignalContents}->FindSignalByName($name,$signal) or die "Could not find $name\n";
$fooData= $server->LoadSignal($signal,$timeRange);
```

The code runs, and doesn't die on the second to last line.  But every time I look at the **$signal** object, it's empty.  The time range and names are correct, because I verified it was interpretting it correctly.

Additionally, I tried to force the return type better using the Win32::OLE::Variant library, as:

```
$server->{SignalContents}->FindSignalByName($name,Variant(VT_DISPATCH|VT_BYREF,$signal)) or die "Could not find $name\n";
```

But this didn't help...still an empty **$signal** object no matter how I try.  Any ideas?